# clojure - function not returning a lazy sequence

Tags: clojure

I am confused as to why the code below goes into an infinite loop and does not return a lazy sequence when I am calling `lazy-seq`:

```
 (= (take 5 ((fn [func se] 
               (lazy-seq 
                (reduce (fn [acc item] 
                          (conj acc (func (last acc) item)))
                        [(first se)] (rest se)))) 
             + 
             (range)))
     [0 1 3 6 10])
```

The repl just spins as range gets infinitely called.

How can I make this function behave lazily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to construct a lazy-sequence you need to return a sequence that is realized as needed.

What you're doing in your function is just wrapping an infinite reduction in a `lazy-seq` call.

There's a pattern that usually works and is realizing a new element only as needed:

```
 (lazy-seq
     (cons element (recursion ..
```

That means if you want to build a lazy reduce you will be doing something along these lines:

```
 (fn [f s init]
    (lazy-seq
        (let [acc (f (first s) init)]
           (cons acc (recur f (rest s) acc))
```

In that case your returned sequence will exist in memory as a partially realized sequence

```
  (0 1 3 (recur + (rest s) 3))
```

With the remaining elements existing only `logically` as a to-be-called recursion.

You can have a look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227503/clojure-reduce-reductions-and-infinte-lists) explaining the non laziness of reduce.

Comment: Would recur not have the same result as reduce and it will just spin?

Comment: No because reduce needs to iterate until the sequence is empty so you can have the final result, the function proposed recurs only as needed. You could have used `reductions` also

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to recreate reductions to increase my clojure knowledge so it is just for fun

Comment: ok, you consider your question answered as why you cannot wrap reduce in a lazy-seq call?