# partition a lazy sequence - after - a predicate truth test changes

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

Consider sentences stored in a lazy sequence: Each word is one entry, punctuation however belongs to the words:

```
("It's" "time" "when" "it's" "time!" "What" "did" "you" "say?" "Nothing!")
```

It should now be "partitioned" in sentences. I wrote a helper function last-punctuated?, which checks if the last character is a non-alphabet character. (no problem with this)

Desired result:

```
(("It's" "time" "when" "it's" "time!") ("What" "did" "you" "say?") ("Nothing!"))
```

Everything should stay lazy. Unfortunately I could not use partition-by: This function splits up *before* the result of a given predicate changes, meaning the punctuated entries are not interpreted as the last entry in the sub sequence.

Comment: [useful.seq/partition-between](https://github.com/amalloy/useful/blob/develop/src/flatland/useful/seq.clj#L224)

Answer (score 1):

i would propose using a `lazy-seq`. Can't think of anything better than this (maybe it's not really the best):

```
(defn parts [items pred]
  (lazy-seq
   (when (seq items)
     (let [[l r] (split-with (complement pred) items)]
       (cons (concat l (take 1 r))
             (parts (rest r) pred))))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (let [items '("It's" "time" "when" "it's"
                    "time!" "What" "did" "you"
                    "say?" "Nothing!")]
        (parts items (comp #{\? \! \. \,} last)))

(("It's" "time" "when" "it's" "time!") ("What" "did" "you" "say?") ("Nothing!"))

user> (let [items '("what?" "It's" "time" "when" "it's"
                    "time!" "What" "did" "you"
                    "say?" "Nothing!")]
        (parts items (comp #{\? \! \. \,} last)))

(("what?") ("It's" "time" "when" "it's" "time!") ("What" "did" "you" "say?") ("Nothing!"))

user> (let [items '("what?" "It's" "time" "when" "it's"
                    "time!" "What" "did" "you"
                    "say?" "Nothing!")]
        (realized? (parts items (comp #{\? \! \. \,} last))))

false
```

**update:** probably the same approach with `iterate` would be better.

```
(defn parts [items pred]
  (->> [nil items]
       (iterate (fn [[_ items]]
                  (let [[l r] (split-with (complement pred) items)]
                    [(concat l (take 1 r)) (rest r)])))
       rest
       (map first)
       (take-while seq)))
```

Comment: In terms of simplicity, I like the first (lazy-seq) version the most. For me it's very clear, it doesn't have the overheads, the iterate one has to take: like: initializing with nil, the rest/(map first) thing. The question would be: Why do you think the iterate approach would be better? Does it have to do with recursion and the stack-trace? (like with loop/recur)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be actually expressed easily by generating a new sequence, containing "split tokens" and then doing `partition-by` basing on a different predicate.:

```
(def punctuation? #{\. \! \?})

(def words ["It's" "time" "when" "it's" "time!" "What" "did" "you" "say?" "Nothing!"])

(defn partition-sentences [ws]
  (->> ws
    (mapcat #(if (punctuation? (last %)) [% :br] [%]))
    (partition-by #(= :br %))
    (take-nth 2)))


(println (take 20 (partition-sentences (repeatedly #(rand-nth words))))
```

Comment: looks good.. I cannot study it deeply right now... but, just: are you sure that's still lazy in the end? ah, and: one improvement: there is mapcat which will make the flatten go away.

Comment: I've changed to using `mapcat` as you suggested. The updated example shows, that this will never force realization of the whole sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I like the creativity of the approach. It works perfectly. In the end I decided to use one of the solutions (iterate/lazy-seq) suggested by leetwinski, because I found the use of a "stopper" a bit too hacky, but that's personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the input differs from the size of the output often the answer is to use `reduce`.

```
(defn last-word? [word]
  (assert word)
  (or (.endsWith word "!")
      (.endsWith word "?")))

(defn make-sentence [in]
  (reduce (fn [acc ele]
            (let [up-to-current-sentence (vec (butlast acc))
                  last-word-last-sentence (-> acc last last)
                  new-sentence? (when last-word-last-sentence (last-word? last-word-last-sentence))
                  current-sentence (vec (last acc))]
              (if new-sentence?
                (conj acc [ele])
                (conj up-to-current-sentence (conj current-sentence ele)))))
          [] in))
```

Unfortunately `reduce` needs an end, so can't be made to work with lazy input. There's discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227503/clojure-reduce-reductions-and-infinite-lists).

Comment: `reduce` is not lazy at all... so i guess it is not the thing the op wanted.

Comment: Was just contemplating that very fact. Was about to lookup whether a `reduce` can be made lazy. You might know. `reduce` seems like the 'go to' for this question. Would be nice to know if it can be made lazy.