# Where is the tail position in my Clojure loop?

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

Clojure is saying that I can't call `recur` from a non-tail-position.

Is this not the tail position?

What *is* the tail position in my loop then?

```
(loop [i 20]
    (for [x (range 1 21)]
      (if (zero? (rem i x))
        i
        (recur (+ i 1)))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` does not do what you think it does; it is not an imperative loop. It is a list comprehension, or sequence-generator. Therefore, there is not a return or iterate call at its end, so you cannot place `recur` there.

It would seem you probably do not need either `loop` or `recur` in this expression at all; the `for` is all you need to build a sequence, but it's not clear to me exactly what sequence you wish to build.

Comment: It's a project euler problem: What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Comment: Coming from an object-oriented background I feel like I need two loops: one which counts from 1 to infinity as i, the other which divides i by the numbers 1 through 20. The loop should recur only when there is a remainder.

Comment: in that case, you are trying to find a single value, not a sequence, therefor you do not need a `for` expression here at all. you could use `loop` but `reduce` is much much more idiomatic... nearly all loops in Clojure can be expressed as a `reduce`. however, since you don't know how many you will need to test, `loop` might be better here since you don't know the end of the iteration

Comment: Fold over lazy seq. Nor does it need to be infinite: 20! is obviously evenly divisible by all numbers 1-20. Although 20! is rather large....which I assume is the point of the exercise...

Comment: @JaredSmith not really -- reduce is not lazy, so folding over an infinite sequence (as I think you imply) is not good Clojure. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5227513/3758484

Comment: @johnbakers ah yes, would totally blow up the heap. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: you could however use a filter and/or a take/drop on a map, which are both lazy, to achieve your result if you are crafty, therefore getting a lazy result without loop or reduce. there are many ways to express this problem

Comment: I think I need a reduce within a loop

Comment: @JacksonGariety yes, that is one way to do this. after you're done with that, to really understand Clojure, write it again using a combination of map, filter, take or drop. in general, don't use `loop` unless you have no other choice -- it is much more elegant and powerful to use functional idioms.

Answer (score 1):

Further to [@JohnBaker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36434301/1562315), any `recur` refers to the (nearest) enclosing `loop` or `fn` (which may be dressed as a `letfn` or a `defn`). There is no such thing in your snippet. So there is nothing for the `recur` to be in tail position to.

But just replace the `for` with `loop`, and you get

```
(loop [i 20]
  (loop [x 1]
    (if (zero? (rem i x))
      i
      (recur (+ i 1)))))
```

... which evaluates to `20`,no doubt what you intended.

However, the outer `loop` is never recurred to, so might at well be a `let`:

```
(let [i 20]
  (loop [x 1]
    (if (zero? (rem i x))
      i
      (recur (+ i 1)))))
```

The `recur` is in tail position because there is nothing left to do in that control path through the `loop` form: the `recur` form *is* the returned value. Both arms of an `if` have their own tail position.

There are some other disguised `if`s that have their own tail position: `or`s and `and`s are such.