# "Can't recur here" error in CLJS

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm new to Clojure(script) and am playing around with the latter. I have a very simple piece of code that I'm trying to recur on to retrieve all the child nodes under a given element.

```
(defn psel [pr ch]
  (let [c (nl-arr (.-children pr))]
    (for [child c]
      ;; (println child)))) THIS WORKS FINE
      (recur child nil))))
```

But I get `Can't recur here at line 14 src/hello_seymore/core.cljs`

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the expected result of your function?

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant based on the code snippet?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434246/where-is-the-tail-position-in-my-clojure-loop. Basically `for` is not a typical for loop but a "list comprehension" which returns a seq of values you build for each element (simply speaking).

Comment: Thank you! That post explained it. Closing